# WPF DataGrid Horizontal Fill or Scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm working on an application in WPF that contains a DataGrid. I allow the users to select columns that they want to view or hide, and I also allow the users to resize the columns. When the user hides too many columns, or resizes the columns to the point of being more narrow than the width of the DataGrid, I want the columns to operate as if one of them had a `*` width. When the user expands the columns wider than the width of the DataGrid, I want to allow horizontal scrolling. I'm probably missing something simple, as I haven't worked with WPF in a number of months, but everything I try seems to result in unwanted behavior.

```
<DataGrid Margin="12,29,12,41" Name="sanitized" ItemsSource="{Binding sanitized}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MouseDoubleClick="sanitized_MouseDoubleClick" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Path=sanitized}" IsReadOnly="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource GenericCellStyle}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="sanitized" Binding="{Binding Path=sanitized}" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource GenericCellStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="sanitized" Binding="{Binding Path=sanitized}" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource GenericCellStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="sanitized" Binding="{Binding Path=sanitized}" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource GenericCellStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="sanitized" Binding="{Binding Path=sanitized}" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource GenericCellStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="sanitized" Binding="{Binding Path=sanitized}" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource GenericCellStyle}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My GenericCellStyle is just to enable the DataGridCheckBoxColumn to be checked on the first click on a row, and to switch the SelectionUnit between Cell and FullRow:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="GenericCellStyle">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="sanitized_Click" />
</Style>
```

Code behind:

```
private void sanitized_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null && cell.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn)
    {
        sanitized.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.Cell;
        if (!cell.IsEditing)
        {
            if (!cell.IsFocused)
            {
                cell.Focus();
            }
            DependencyObject dep = cell;
            while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridRow))
            {
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }
            if (dep != null)
            {
                int itemIndex = sanitized.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(dep);
                var selected = (sanitized)sanitizes.Items[itemIndex];
                selected.sanitized= !selected.sanitized;
                // TODO: Move the call to NotifyChange into the sanitized propery.
                selected.NotifyChange("sanitized");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sanitized.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
    }
}
```

This makes it so you can either select the CheckBoxColumn individually, or select the whole row if you click anywhere else.

I have no RowDefinitions or ColumnDefinitions on the Grid containing the DataGrid. I have tried adding a ColumnDefinition with a width of both Auto and * with no change in behavior.

If I set the width of one of the columns to `*`, I cannot seem to enable scrolling. The columns' combined widths are fixed to the width of the DataGrid.

When I do not set the width of one of the columns to `*`, if a user chooses to hide all optional columns, I get the pesky empty cell to the right of my data.

I need some option that allows me a minimum total column width of the width of the DataGrid, but still allows me to stretch my columns wider than that if I want to and enable horizontal scrolling.

<sub>* Feel free to ridicule my code and markup, constructive criticism always welcome!</sub>